# How to get keyboard input of "CTRL L" command in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Is this the correct way of taking input from the keyboard (`CTRL+L`)?

```
dim WshShell
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wait(2)
WshShell.SendKeys("^108")
wait(2)
```

or

```
dim WshShell
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wait(2)
WshShell.SendKeys("^l")
wait(2)
```

Comment: Are you trying to read input from the command line in VBScript/WSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to send a CTRL-L using `SendKeys` is like this:-

```
WshShell.SendKeys("^l")
```

Here is the MSDN reference for the `SendKeys` method to get more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: Hi @Adobe_14, if this answers the question, please accept it as the answer or upvote it for future searchers.